# How many of the Frenchmen who volunteered for service in the Wehrmacht were former POWs?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, vichy-france

During World War II, a number of Frenchmen volunteered for service in the Wehrmacht. For the purposes of this question, these men came from two sources: 1) genuine volunteers (freiwillige or "free willed individuals), and 2) former prisoners of war, who saw service in the Wehrmacht as a "lesser evil" than captivity.

Of the Frenchmen who served in the Wehrmacht,* how many were former POWs who only "volunteered" to escape captivity? The reason for the question is that the Germans were quite successful in getting former Soviet POWs [(Hiwis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiwi_(volunteer))to enlist. How successful were they with Frenchmen who were under similar duress?

*Many of these went into the so-called [Legion_of_French_Volunteers_Against_Bolshevism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_French_Volunteers_Against_Bolshevism), but some went directly into the Waffen SS. (I'm not talking about the [Milice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milice) or other anti-partisan groups.)

Comment: This is no longer a duplicate. I have reworded the question to focus on the success of the Germans in recruiting former French POWs, not "volunteers" generally.

Comment: If you consider only Wehrmacht and Waffen SS, number could not be more than 10 000.  I doubt anyone volunteered for Eastern Front just to avoid POW camps. Vichy troops are something entirely different, but their loyalty was divided.